# Joomla URL params in post request

Tags: url, post, joomla, request

Recently I have been playing around with Joomla. I noticed Joomla post request submits request parameters both in form fields and also in URL parameters. For example, when I clicked "Users"-->"Edit" button, a request is sent to following URL (I used Joomla demo site). Also, additional parameters are sent as form field.

http://joomla30.cloudaccess.net/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=users

My question is: why does Joomla send some request parameters in request URL instead of sending all post data as form fields? What is the reason of mixing GET and POST parameters?

**Update:** I googled several articles about including post request params both in request string and form body. These articles (or QA pages) state that the request still is a post request; therefore, it is not mixing GET and POST. However, these articles don't provide clear reason why we shouldn't (or should) include some post request parameters in query string while including others in request body.

Comment: I think the convention is to send form and backend pagination data using POST, and access current page using url (GET). This separation is actually quite comfortable while navigating around various backend sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bad habit from the older days. Some extensions did not use the proper API to access request data, but accessed the superglobals (or the query string) directly. So, in short, nowadays there is no reason to mix GET and POST.